# SSRS "Losing" Parameters Passed to Subreport

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've set up a number of reports in SSRS.  Each of these reports are well designed and work as expected.

A request was made to have a number of these reports tied into a single "master" report.  I've set up the working reports as subreports, and populated all parameters of the first subreport from the "master" report.  I have checked and double checked this fact.

When I attempt to run the report processing seems excessively long.  In place of the first subreport SSRS renders `Error:  Subreport could not be shown.`

I checked the log file and I'm getting an error:
`processing!ReportServer_0-3!e58!04/11/2016-19:42:15::e ERROR: An error has occurred while processing a sub-report.  Details: One or more parameters were not specified for the subreport ... Report.Stack trace: at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.SubReport.FinalizeErrorMessageAndThrow() at Microsoft.ReportingServices.OnDemandReportRendering.SubReport.RetrieveSubreport()`

I've also checked the ReportServer ExecutionLogStorage and I can see that all of my parameters are populating in the parameter column.  The parameter string is running about 5k characters.

Some more details:  The subreport contains 7 parameters:

- Administrator - single value
- ReportDate - single value
- ClientStatus - multiselect
- DeptStatus - multiselect
- Client - multiselect
- AccessType - single value
- DataOnly - single value

These parameters are mirrored in the "master" report.  I've tried passing the multiselect parameters using both `=Parameters!ClientStatus.Value` and the `=Split(join(Parameters!ClientStatus.Value,","),",")` method, but I'm honestly not sure which parameter is missing from the subreport.  That information isn't recorded anywhere as far as I can tell.

We've mostly abandoned this combined, "master" report, but I'd like to stay on top of this as I'm wondering if it might affect other reports in a more subtle way.

If I can provide more information, please let me know.

Comment: Make sure the multi-value parameters from the main report to the subreport are passed as [@parameterName], not as "=Parameters!parameterName.Value".

Comment: @ErayBalkanli Wait, could you elaborate here?  Using the ClientStatus parameter from above, when editing the expression the final expression is `=Parameters!ClientStatus.Value` but when I view it in the parameters menu of the subreport properties window the expresion above translates to `[@ClientStatus]`.  I've set up a multiselect parameter like this before and it worked out fine.

Comment: When you use [@parameterName] or Join(Parameters!parameterName.Value) to pass a parameter from the report to subreport, does it solve your problem here? Have u tried?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli  Yes, I've tried both versions.  Neither result in a rendered report in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can lookup the passed parameters by querying the ExecutionLog in the SSRS-database.

```
SELECT [InstanceName]
      ,[ReportID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[RequestType]
      ,[Format]
      ,[Parameters]
      ,[TimeStart]
      ,[TimeEnd]
      ,[TimeDataRetrieval]
      ,[TimeProcessing]
      ,[TimeRendering]
      ,[Source]
      ,[Status]
      ,[ByteCount]
      ,[RowCount]
  FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog]
```

You need to run the report on the SSRS-portal, obviously, instead of locally in VS or Report Designer...

Comment: amazing bit of troubleshooting advice! Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Do all of your parameters in subreport have a value ? 

If not, are parameters checked with "accept null value" ?

Comment: They are set up to receive a value from the master report.  I've set up each parameter of the subreport to have a value passed from the master report.  "accept null value" wouldn't be an option here - the parameters MUST be populated.  Is there any way I can see what is actually being passed to the subreport?

Comment: BTW, this would be better posted as a comment on the original question rather than an answer.

Comment: "accept null value" is a parameter of the report that you use as subreport.
If all of parameters are populated in master report, it's the only thing that i see